# Overlaying image logic with JS (and CSS/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css, logic, display

This function is used to display whether or not user input from elementID 'Keys' contains specific keys on a keyboard.

ex: User types in qwerty, qwerty keys displayed as true in table, all other keys displayed as false.

Now I want a green box image (elementID 'a-key-true') or red box image (elementID 'a-key-false') to overlay the keys on the image of the keyboard. The boxes are set to `display:none` by default. Once the function runs, it populates the table and **should** display a green or red box over the keys on the keyboard image.

What is Working: Displays True or False for n in table

Partial Functionality: Displays True image if n=true, but also displays True image if n=false

What is Broken: Never displays false image

```
//Displays Key Status
function keyPresent() {
    var str = document.getElementById('Keys').value;
    var n = "";
    var x = document.getElementById('a-key-true');
    var y = document.getElementById('a-key-false');

    n = str.includes("a");

    //Works: Displays True or False for n in table
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "a = " + n;

    //Broken: Displays True image if n=true, but also displays True image if n=false
    //Broken: Never displays false image
    if(n=true){
        y.style.display = 'none';
        x.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
        y.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(n)` is sufficient. `if(n==true)` or `if(n===true)` are fine. But `if(n=true)` *sets `n` to `true`* and then tests if that is truthy (spoiler alert: it is), thus your condition will always pass.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol Wow that was a bonehead mistake. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey we all have days like that. Just earlier today I was blazing through a test for a new feature and everything was working flawlessly, until the whole thing fell apart before I missed a `}` :D